# Div positionated absolute to img should't move

Tags: html, css

i have got the following problem: there are two siblings div within the father, one with an image (position relative and class home-image) and the other (position absolute and box-circle) with a child (a div called white-circle with a circle behind the image with position absolute).
My problem is: the circle should stay behind the image and moving away when i change resolution.

[image]

[image]

This is the relative css:

```
.box-circle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.home-image{
  z-index: 10;
}
.relative{
  position: relative;
}
.white-circle{
      position: absolute;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 25rem;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
  top: 12rem;
    right: 8rem;
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing your HTML structure with words, you should share that part of code, it would be much clearer

Comment: Can you share your code to help you

Comment: please create a fiddle with the minimum markup and style necesary to show the issue. How and where the circle should move away?

Comment: I have not share because i'm using wordpress with salient and i gives a bunch of code, anyway now i'll share

Answer (score 1):

The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of a **positioned** element,so insert `position` property to `.home-image` like this:

```
.home-image{
  z-index: 10;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: @Kaddath, hi my friend,  the `div`  is described as "position relative and class home-image" in the question no `image`.he describe there are two siblings div.

Comment: my bad, that's the very reason i asked the OP to clarify about the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```css
.home-image{
 z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px auto  auto;
  text-align: center;
}
 
.white-circle{
    position: absolute;
    width: 25rem;
    height: 25rem;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/12F8N.png"></div>
 
<div class="white-circle"> </div>
```